# Should I have to activate venv after activating conda environment for pip to work properly?

Tags: python, python-venv

I'm not sure if this is just coincidental, but yesterday after rebooting and running a windows upgrade, I receive an SSL Module error with pip. I was receiving with my System Python using Anaconda3 as well as all of my virtual environments. I uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda and things seem to be working fine there. However, I found that the only way for my virtual environments to behave properly is to first activate my conda environment, and then activate virtual environment on top of that. I did not have to do that before. Is this expected behavior?

For instance,

```
(base) python -m venv .venv
conda deactivate
.venv\Scripts\activate
(.venv) pip install numpy
```

traceback:

```
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/numpy/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

However, if I do

```
(base) python -m venv .venv
(base) .venv\Scripts\activate
(.venv) (base) pip install numpy
(.venv) (base) pip freeze
numpy==1.18.1
```

Then everything works fine. This took me forever to figure out and I still don't necessarily understand why I'm getting this behavior. Could somebody help enlighten me?

Comment: Mixing `conda` and `pip`+`venv` is a disaster waiting to happen. Is there a reason you aren't sticking to one? E.g. either using `conda` for package management and installation OR using `venv` for management and `pip` for installation.

Comment: I would highly prefer to use the latter option, but I'm running into the SSL Module error any time I try to go that route. Whenever I first started using Python ~a year ago I only used Conda, but where I am today I see the value in keeping different projects isolated in their respective environments

Comment: I would say it's not unlikely your installation is already be broken. Just a question - why didn't you use `conda` to create your environments instead of messing with `venv` within `conda`?

Comment: I suppose the main reason would be out of ignorance that I even could. That, and it feels like any tutorial I see out there uses ``venv`` so I figured that it was more standard

Comment: did you try doing `which python` in both the instances?

Comment: At this point I would suggest starting from scratch, or, at the very least, uninstalling Anaconda for vanilla Python (this may allow you to continue using existing `venv` environments). Note that neither package manager is more "standard." When it comes to package managers, consistency is very very important. Your issue likely stems from conflicts between `conda` and `venv`. In general, `venv` should be used for vanilla Python distributions. An exception to the consistency rule is using `pip` with `conda` environments because some packages are only available on PyPI.

Comment: Additionally, what pip version are you using? Did you try to update pip?

Comment: @iz_ so just to make sure I'm clear on following your approach, your recommendation is to completely uninstall Anaconda (which at this point includes my Python distribution) and then to just install vanilla Python 3.x. My only question there, is how do I overcome the SSL Module import error if I continue receiving it? At this point, I'm suspecting that I would.

Comment: @shub I'm using the latest ``pip``. ``where python`` always returns the path to Python install in Anaconda ``Anaconda3\python.exe`` and when the ``venv`` is activated, it returns both paths ``Anaconda3\python.exe`` and ``.venv\Scripts\python.exe``

Comment: The only issue I can think about is that your pip version outside the conda environment is different. Because this is an ssl certificate error and it has nothing to do with using 2 different package managers. So I would recommend checking your pip versions for all the environments you have.

Comment: That SSL error sounds familiar, have you been able to find anything on the subject? While I don’t agree that you should ditch Conda entirely, I do think that starting over from scratch is probably the best thing to do. Also, did you forget a word in your comment: _Whenever I first started using Python ~a year ago I only used Conda..._ ?

Comment: Try doing `which pip` in both the cases along with `pip --version` and see if there is any discrepancy.

Comment: @RocketSocks22 It's completely your choice if you want to use `venv` or `conda`; I wouldn't recommend one over the other. The only reason I mentioned uninstalling Anaconda is because you stated that most of your environments are `venv`. I do agree that SSL errors aren't typically a result of package conflicts. However, you may run into a bunch of unexpected errors down the road if you continue mixing both. I've made this mistake in the past and spent countless hours trying to fix errors caused by a faulty environment. If you continue having SSL errors, I can try and help you fix them :)

Comment: Just want to say thanks for the help to everyone! I'm going to have to hold off on trying to reach a better solution for a few days or so but I appreciate all of the feedback. I think I have more than enough ideas from this thread to fix whatever's going on